# Problem in importing .csv file to database in Cpanel

Tags: mysql

I am having problem in importing a .csv file to database in Cpanel. Can anybody help me in this?

Thanks in advance
Mythri

Comment: More information? Errors messages?

Comment: What have you tried ? DO you have some code to show ? What kind of error do you get ? Give us more informations, to help us help you ;-)

Comment: I tried to import (through a button which is there in my cpanel) .csv file and it says "Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1.". I checked the fields and its matching and correct. do u want me to attach .csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the MySQL client within CPanel, I think the best would be to give an example of the data in the first 5 lines.

Comment: Hi, am not able to attach files. how do i show the example of csv

Comment: If you copy/paste it into the comments ? or edit your question and then use the {} button to formulate it, try to see if that works.